# Can´t display var text on map script

Tags: javascript, laravel

I´m using Laravel and trying to display data from DB about all the locations.

Coordinates works but the text of gps[i].placeName and gps[i].url is not correct. Why is not displayed correctly?

here is what is displayed
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUSOg.png

```
<script>

const gps = @json($gpss);

var map = L.map('map').setView([37.182214, -3.600884], 12);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 17
})

.addTo(map);

for (let i=gps.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 


L.control.scale(map);
L.marker([(gps[i].gps1), (gps[i].gps2)], {draggable: false}).addTo(map).bindPopup("<a href=gps[i].url)>gps[i].placeName)</a>");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do like this. you have missed to concatenat the variable.

```
L.marker([(gps[i].gps1), (gps[i].gps2)], {draggable: false}).addTo(map)
.bindPopup("<a href='"+gps[i].url+"')>"+gps[i].placeName+")</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the variable value in:

```
bindPopup("<a href='" + gps[i].url + "')>" + gps[i].placeName + ")</a>");
```

Or use a template literal:

```
bindPopup(`<a href='${gps[i].url)>gps[i].placeName)}'</a>`);
```